# Send notification from Raspberry pi to Android app

Tags: android, push-notification, raspberry-pi

I have raspberry pi and an android app. I want to send notifications from the pi to my smartphone app. Is this possible?﻿

The notification needs to be on a individual user basis

Firebase and Google Cloud Messaging seem to be an option.

The pi will act as a server and the android app a client. 
The android app does not sent information back.

Again, is the above possible using either Firebase or Google Cloud Messaging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually is possible, you need to setup the server and use the Firebase Admin SDK, see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup). You could have a Python server (for example Django), Node.js, Java or Go server. You can have any of these in the Pi.

With the admin SDK you need only to configure it to have the same project ID as the app, then you can send notifications with the SDK, see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages).

Note that you'll probably need to save the FCM tokens from the clients in the real time database so you can access them through the Admin SDK and simply direct the messages to them. Or you could have your clients subscribe to a [topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/manage-topic-subscriptions) and send the notification to the topic, which is much easier than needing to manage tokens.